# How to import $ from jQuery.min.js into Angular 2 app? name not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, ecmascript-6, systemjs

I have an Angular 2 app using Typescript. I want to use jQuery's `$` for a variety of tasks such as

```
$(document).ready(function(){        // throwing error: "[ts] Cannot find '$'. any"
  console.log("loaded up!");
  $("#main_div").niceScroll();
})
```

I have imported the jQuery.min.js file into my app via index.html like so:

```
<script src="app/libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However, I have not imported anything into the `app.component.ts` file in regards to the jQuery code. Is it necessary, and if so, how do I import it?

```
import { GenericService } from './services/Generic.service';       // did not do this
import $ from './libs/jquery.min.js';                              // tried this but does not work
```

Surprisingly, my code worked yesterday as I was developing, but not today when I ran `npm start`. Could anyone help me out with this import process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do a

```
typings install jquery --ambient --save
```

to install the type definition file. Remove the `import $ from './libs/jquery.min.js';` and add a reference to the `d.ts` file at the top of your `app.component.ts` like so:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/jquery.d.ts"/>
```

Since you're already loading the Javascript file in your index you only need the typings for it, so TypeScript knows, that those names and methods of jQuery exist.

Comment: What does `/// <reference path="../typings/jquery.d.ts"/>` do? It seems like it is commented out so I am confused.

Comment: It tells the TypeScript compiler to include that file when searching for type definitions. [More info here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html)

Comment: @KangzeHuang More information here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces%20and%20Modules.md#-reference-ing-a-module

Comment: If I have a smaller library such as `jquery.nicescroll`, how can I get the typings file for it? `typings install jquery --ambient --save` seems like someone manually converted it.

Comment: I couldn't find any typings for that and yes, someone created such a file by hand. You could go the hard way and try to write such a file based on that js or you could remove that reference again and just do a `declare var $: any;` if you don't care about the auto completion and all that.

Comment: Does this mean lots of smaller JS libraries will not be compatible with Angular2+TS unless they are manually coverted?

Comment: Yes, sadly. But you can still use it with that `declare`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add Jquery with typings :

```
typings install jquery --ambient --save
```

Then in your index :

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And normally typescript will do the job :)